# Validación en javascript no funciona en dispositivos iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

Tengo un problema raro, resulta que tengo ese código que es para anotarse para un evento pero no se puede anotar en el mismo dia ni días anteriores, en la compu y en android funciona perfecto, pero en los iPhones cada vez que toco el campo de la fecha me sale el error: No se puede seleccionar una fecha duplicada, pero te deja seleccionar lo único es que cada vez que clico en el campo de la fecha me salta el mensaje: No se puede seleccionar una fecha duplicada, solo en iPhone.
Alguien me puede ayudar con eso, ¿que se puede hacer para que no aparezca ese error en android?

Les dejo el codigo:

```js
  var fechas = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < fechas.length; i++) {
    fechas[i].addEventListener('change', validarFechas);
  }

  function validarFechas() {
    var fechasSeleccionadas = [];
    var fechasDuplicadas = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < fechas.length; i++) {
      if (fechas[i].value !== "" && fechasSeleccionadas.includes(fechas[i].value)) {
        fechasDuplicadas = true;
        break;
      }
      fechasSeleccionadas.push(fechas[i].value);
    }
    var fechaHoy = new Date();
    fechaHoy.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (this.valueAsDate <= fechaHoy) {
      this.setCustomValidity('Elija una fecha posterior a la de hoy');
      alert('Elija una fecha posterior a la de hoy');
    } else if (fechasDuplicadas) {
      this.setCustomValidity('No se puede elegir fechas duplicadas');
      alert('No se puede elegir fechas duplicadas');
    } else {
      this.setCustomValidity('');
    }
  }
```

```html
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha1" name="fecha1_CO" required><br>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha2" name="fecha2_CO"><br>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha3" name="fecha3_CO"><br>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha4" name="fecha4_CO"><br>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha5" name="fecha5_CO"><br>
```

Les comento que antes usaba el atributo `input type="date"` pensando que era eso, entonces opte por usar otra librería de fechas como Datepicker y lo mismo; al final use la libreria flatpickr, pero sigue igual, en los iPhones me salta el error cada vez que quiero elegir una fecha, me deja elegir pero me muestra el error cuando no debería. El código funciona perfecto en la compu y en android.

Ahi deje el codigo en el Sniper, ya veran que en la compu funciona perfecto pero en el Iphone no valida las fechas.

Otro tema tambien es el estilo, yo uso bootstrap y en los android me muestra 1 fila por input date, y se ve la fila completa, sin embargo en los iphone se ve el input date muy chico, no se completa toda la fila.

Comment: ¿Esto se está ejecutando en un navegador? Si es así, ¿estás seguro que el diferenciador es que sea un dispositivo iPhone? Es decir, ¿funciona bien en safari sobre Windows/Linux y funciona mal en Safari,  Chrome y Firefox en iPhone? Si no es así, ¿dónde se está ejecutando?

Comment: Hola@jachguate gracias por contestar, si, el problema es solo en los iphone, si entro en el safari desde una mac funciona perfecto, en linux/windows tambien

Comment: Hola, puse tu código en un snippet, pero no parece funcionar en Windows, que es donde yo estoy editando la pregunta. Es mejor si completas un [mcve].

Comment: Ojo con `toISOString()` esto transformará tu fecha a UTC-0. Digamos por ejemplo que tu estas en UTC -2 y pruebas esto a las 10 de la noche, la fecha que te saldrá es la del día siguiente

Comment: Hola @Yussef ahiu cambie el codigo

Comment: Hola @jachguate ahi puse en el snippet

Comment: @SidneyAlan-DesignerProgra Yo no puedo ayudarte....no tengo iphone para probar tu código. Pero me queda la duda si tu en tu iphone y con este snippet muestra el mismo comportamiento anómalo?

Comment: @Yussef yo tampoco tengo iphone, estoy recibiendo quejas de los que tienen iphone.